# cannot import play.db.jpa.Model into my model

Tags: jpa, model, playframework

I cannot somehow import the `play.db.jpa.Model` lib into my Model, it can only find `play.db.ebean.Model`. Is there any way to import this?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because `play.db.jpa.Model` is Play 1.x and `play.db.ebean.Model` is Play 2.x.

To use JPA in Play 2.x, see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaJPA

Comment: oh really? but why cannot i find the ``find()`` method of Model then?

Comment: now do i have to implement the find method on my own?

like..

   ``public static User find(Long id){``
        ``return JPA.em().find(User.class, id); }``

Comment: yes...its one of the pros/cons of Play 2.x...its less magic, so more work, but because its less magic, its clearer whats going on.

Answer (score 4):

The class play.db.jpa.Model isn't available from play 2.0 on. The solution I found to this problem is:

- In `YourProject/conf/application.conf`, declare the JPA configuration:

> db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
>  db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
>   db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

And the persistence unit:

> jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

- Create a new Package named META-INF at YourProject/conf/
- Inside this package create a file named `persistence.xml`:

> ```
>  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
>                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
>                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>                  version="2.0">
>
>         <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
>             <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
>             <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
>             <properties>
>                 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
>             </properties>
>         </persistence-unit>
>
>
> </persistence>
> ```

- At `YourProject/project/Build.scala` modify the dependencies to add the following:

> val appDependencies = Seq(
>     // Add your project dependencies here,  
>     javaCore,
>     javaJdbc,
>     javaJpa,
>     "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.1.Final"
>   )

Also you can disable Ebean if you aren't going to use it with:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  ebeanEnabled := false 
)
```

- After this, run play eclipse on your project and refresh.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit" in application.conf is the part I spent a few hours trying to figure out.  Still haven't found it documented anywhere but in the source to JPAPlugin. :(

Comment: @RodneyGitzel its in the 2.2 docs under JPA: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA , see the last part of "Creating a Persistence Unit"

Comment: @chris unfortunately it was left out of the 2.1 docs:  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaJPA

Comment: @RodneyGitzel oh, what a bummer. +1 - hopefully this will save someone else their time / sanity!